# Low quality posts

Tags: discussion, etiquette

The low quality posts review queue has become available to me. As I write this post the queue is empty and there is nothing to serve as an examples of what kind post gets put into it. So I ask: what qualifies a post for relegation to this queue? I ask because there a couple or recent posts that I personally consider low quality, but I don't want to flag them as "very low quality" without having some understanding on the site policy or precedents on this subject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Community ♦](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) , which is a background process, automatically assigns every new post (questions and answers) a "score" based on some heuristics and if found to be low, it places the post in this review queue. Some of the reasons a post can end up in this queue are:

- Low character count that's probably just above the bare minimum of 30 ([example 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14545/5)). Often times, this is a single sentence question or merely a link to an image/website or sometimes even a one line answer or comment, all of which are discouraged ([example 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10745/5), [example 3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9475/5); need 10k to view).
- Only a code block is present or if the ratio of characters in code to text is high ([example 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14668/5), [example 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/9816/1), [example 3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/12000/5))
- The post has a high percentage of words that are not recognized as English and are not in a code block ([example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/15791/1)). Often this is because someone has forgotten to format as code.

The above list is not exhaustive and the exact heuristics are not public either, but you get the idea. All of the above examples were once in the review queue. In addition to this, if the score is *very low*, Community also raises a flag for moderator attention ([example 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16136/5), [example 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11495/5); both need 10k) and one of the moderators decides whether or not the post needs to be deleted or left alone.

As for reviewing items in the queue — sometimes, a short answer is all there is to be said, but in almost every other instance, the post can be improved with a bit more explanation. Users can mark these as "Looks good" or recommend/vote for deletion/closure or flag/edit them or do nothing.

The trend that I've seen is that spam, questions/comments as answers, etc. get flagged for moderator attention and proper answers to questions get marked "Looks good". Some editing for context or a comment prodding them to add it would be nice, but no harm either way. Poor questions get votes to close.

---

The important point to note is that "low quality" here simply means that the *possibility* of it being badly formatted or spam or just a code dump is high and it needs a human to verify it. It should **not** be used to judge the technical quality of an answer or a question. So if someone uses a `For` loop, it's not a good reason to flag as "low quality" :)

Comment: Also, this "score" is assigned when the user hits "Submit" and the post is immediately placed in the queue or flagged. Subsequent edits (even in the grace period) will not remove it from the queue or the flag.

Comment: And please, don't mistake _low_ quality for _frog_ quality